# Issue with Woocommerce and wp_list_categories displaying empty categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code pulling together a category:

```
$args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'title_li' => '<h2 class="cat-title">Categories</h2>',
            'exclude' => '588',
            'hide_empty' => '1',
            'show_count' => '1'
            );

wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Which gives me a list of categories to a depth of 2 or 3. Unfortunately for some reason the empty sub categories are still being displayed and I cannot see why.

Comment: Have you tried changing `'hide_empty'` to be an integer, instead of a string? By the way, the default is `1`...so you *shouldn't* need to include it at all.

Comment: @mevius I'll tried string, integer and boolean values

Comment: OK, I resolved this - there was some weird interaction going on with one of my product attributes.

Comment: Please answer your question with your solution.